# Formatting SQL Server time(7) using PHP date()

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date, time

In my SQL Server database I have a time field stored as time(7). I have been trying to print this in PHP using echo but I wouldn't work, so I used this code

```
"ReturnDatesAsStrings" =>1
```

and it returned

```
08:35:00.0000000
```

And for the past hour I've been trying to format it into 08:35am using the date() function but have had no luck. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable `ReturnDatesAsStrings` what you get is a `DateTime` object. Obviously, a object cannot be printed with a plain echo, but you have a proper date and all you have to do is to call the [format()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on it. Using strings as intermediate format when PHP can do it for you is a bigger hassle.

Comment: How would I go about doing it your way?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out. Works a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('H:ia', strtotime('08:35:00.0000000')); // 08:35am
```

or, better, use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime('08:35:00.0000000');
echo $date->format('H:ia'); // 08:35am
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date_format( strtotime($datetime_field_in_db), 'g:i A') );
```